# Efficiently Using Multiple Numpy Slices for Random Image Cropping

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have a 4-D numpy array, with the first dimension representing the number of images in a data set, the second and third being the (equal) width and height, and the 4th being the number of channels (3). For example let's say I have 4 color images that are 28*28, so my image data looks like this:

```
X = np.reshape(np.arange(4*28*28*3), (4,28,28,3))
```

I would like to select a random 16*16 width x height crop of each of the 4 images. Critically, I want the crop to be different per-image, i.e I want to generate 4 random (x_offset, y_offset) pairs. In the end I want access to an array of shape (4, 16, 16, 3).

If I were to write this in a for loop it would look something like this:

```
x = np.random.randint(0,12,4)
y = np.random.randint(0,12,4)
for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    cropped_image = X[i, x[i]:x[i]+16, y[i]:y[i]+16, :]
    #Add cropped image to a list or something
```

But I'd like to do it as efficiently as possible and I'm wondering if there's a way to do it with strides and fancy indexing. I've seen the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413582/selecting-multiple-slices-from-a-numpy-array-at-once) question, but can't quite wrap my head around how I might combine something like stride_tricks with random starting points for the strides on the second and third (width and height) axes.

Comment: I just demonstrated a 2d `as_strided` use in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51866135/numpy-summation-with-sliding-window-is-really-slow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Leverage `strided-based` method for efficient patch extraction

We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get sliding windows that would be merely `views` into the input array and hence incur no extra memory overhead and virtually free! We can surely use `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` directly, but the setup work required is hard to manage especially on arrays with higher dimensions. If [`scikit-image`](https://scikit-image.org) is not available, we can directly use the [`source code`](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/util/shape.py) that works standalone.

**Explanation on usage of `view_as_windows`**

The idea with `view_as_windows` is that we feed in the input arg `window_shape` as a tuple of length same as the number of dimensions in the input array whose sliding windows are needed. The axes along which we need to slide are fed with the respective window lengths and rest are fed with `1s`. This would create an array of `views` with `singleton dims/axes` i.e. axes with `lengths=1` corresponding to the `1s` in `window_shape` arg. So, for those cases we might want to index into the zeroth element corresponding to the axes that are fed `1` as the sliding window lengths to have a *squeezed* version of the sliding windows.

Thus, we would have a solution, like so -

```
# Get sliding windows
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows
w = view_as_windows(X, (1,16,16,1))[...,0,:,:,0]

# Index and get our specific windows
out = w[np.arange(X.shape[0]),x,y]

# If you need those in the same format as in the posted loopy code
out = out.transpose(0,2,3,1)
```

Comment: This is a really nice solution, thanks! I'll wait to see if anyone has a concise Numpy only solution before accepting.

Comment: @user3390629 Use the [`linked source code`](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/util/shape.py) that just needs NumPy. Simply copy over that source code file into working directory.