# Insert element into numpy array and get all rolled permutations

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, numpy, matrix

Is there a better way to insert, one by one, elements in an array 
to all posible positions *(n+1 positions)*.

E.g inserting `[1]` to `[6 7 8 9]` should produce:

```
[1 6 7 8 9]
[9 1 6 7 8]
[8 9 1 6 7]
[7 8 9 1 6]
[6 7 8 9 1]
```

So if I insert `A = [1 2 3]` one by one to B = `[6 7 8 9]` it should produce:

```
[1 6 7 8 9]
[9 1 6 7 8]
[8 9 1 6 7]
[7 8 9 1 6]
[6 7 8 9 1]
--------------------
[2 6 7 8 9]
[9 2 6 7 8]
[8 9 2 6 7]
[7 8 9 2 6]
[6 7 8 9 2]
--------------------
[3 6 7 8 9]
[9 3 6 7 8]
[8 9 3 6 7]
[7 8 9 3 6]
[6 7 8 9 3]
--------------------
```

Currently I use `numpy.roll` like this:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
B = np.array([6, 7, 8, 9])

def inject_one(Ad, Bd):
    for i, _ in enumerate(Ad):
        C = np.append(Ad[i], Bd)
        for _ in range(len(C) - 1):
            C = np.roll(C, 1)

t = timeit.Timer(lambda: inject_one(A, B))
print("{:.3f}secs for 1000 iterations".format(t.timeit(number=1000))) 
# > 0.160 secs
```

Comment: `np.append` is just a front end to `np.concatenate`; it isn't a list `append` clone.  As such, it isn't efficient when applied repeatedly in a loop.

Comment: if your problem is scrolling the list so the last number come first you can you write outa = list[-1]+list[:-1]

Comment: You're not so much inserting at every possible position, but instead inserting at the beginning then rolling your list.

Comment: @user3483203 yes thats right... but I will do whatever is faster.

Comment: @JonasWolff your solution was very good why did you deleted it?

Comment: my usual experience with numpy and scipy is that if they have a solution, they will do it lightyears faster than their counter part, so i deleted my post when i saw you already had one. BTW i reuploaded it now ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking for here is known as a [Toeplitz Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix), which is:

> a matrix in which each descending diagonal from left to right is constant

Luckily for you, `scipy` has an easy to use implementation of this:

```
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz

def magic_toeplitz(arr, to_add):
    return toeplitz(np.hstack([to_add, arr[::-1]]), np.hstack([to_add, arr]))

a = [6,7,8,9]
add = [1]
magic_toeplitz(a, add)
```

```
array([[1, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [9, 1, 6, 7, 8],
       [8, 9, 1, 6, 7],
       [7, 8, 9, 1, 6],
       [6, 7, 8, 9, 1]])
```

#### Vectorized way to scale this solution:

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
B = np.array([6, 7, 8, 9])

out = toeplitz(np.hstack([[np.nan], B[::-1]]), np.hstack([np.nan, B]))
out = np.tile(out, (len(A), 1, 1))
m = np.ma.array(out, mask=np.isnan(out))
vals = np.repeat(A, (B.shape[0] + 1)**2).reshape(out.shape)
print(m.filled(vals))
```

```
array([[[1, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [9, 1, 6, 7, 8],
        [8, 9, 1, 6, 7],
        [7, 8, 9, 1, 6],
        [6, 7, 8, 9, 1]],

       [[2, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [9, 2, 6, 7, 8],
        [8, 9, 2, 6, 7],
        [7, 8, 9, 2, 6],
        [6, 7, 8, 9, 2]],

       [[3, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [9, 3, 6, 7, 8],
        [8, 9, 3, 6, 7],
        [7, 8, 9, 3, 6],
        [6, 7, 8, 9, 3]],

       [[4, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [9, 4, 6, 7, 8],
        [8, 9, 4, 6, 7],
        [7, 8, 9, 4, 6],
        [6, 7, 8, 9, 4]],

       [[5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [9, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        [8, 9, 5, 6, 7],
        [7, 8, 9, 5, 6],
        [6, 7, 8, 9, 5]]])
```

Answer (score 3):

**`2D` Case**

We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get sliding windows. [More info on use of `as_strided` based `view_as_windows`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890064/)

The idea is to pad with two copies of the `1D` array alongwith the new value to be added (`1` in this case) and then get `2D` view into it. Being a view, it would be very efficient and would look something like this -

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

def rolling_add(a,val=1):
    a_ext = np.r_[a,val,a]
    return view_as_windows(a_ext,len(a)+1,1)[::-1]
```

We can gain some marginal improvement with a direct usage of `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` to avoid that flipping part : `[::-1]`, but the setup might be difficult to follow for the readers.

Sample run -

```
In [254]: a = np.array([6, 7, 8, 9])

In [255]: rolling_add(a)
Out[255]: 
array([[1, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [9, 1, 6, 7, 8],
       [8, 9, 1, 6, 7],
       [7, 8, 9, 1, 6],
       [6, 7, 8, 9, 1]])
```

Timings (also to showcase the efficiency part) on very large array -

```
In [263]: a = np.random.randint(0,10,10000)

In [264]: %timeit rolling_add(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 58 µs per loop
```

---

**`3D` Case**

Extending to `3D` requires some additional steps, but it's worth it as we can still keep the output as a view and hence virtually free on timings (head down south again!) -

```
def rolling_add3D(a,add_ar):
    a_ext = np.r_[a,0,a]
    a_ext2 = np.repeat(a_ext[None],len(add_ar),0)
    a_ext2[:,len(a)] = add_ar
    return view_as_windows(a_ext2,(1,len(a)+1))[...,0,:][:,::-1]
```

Sample run -

```
In [292]: a
Out[292]: array([6, 7, 8, 9])

In [293]: rolling_add3D(a,[1,2,3])
Out[293]: 
array([[[1, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [9, 1, 6, 7, 8],
        [8, 9, 1, 6, 7],
        [7, 8, 9, 1, 6],
        [6, 7, 8, 9, 1]],

       [[2, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [9, 2, 6, 7, 8],
        [8, 9, 2, 6, 7],
        [7, 8, 9, 2, 6],
        [6, 7, 8, 9, 2]],

       [[3, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [9, 3, 6, 7, 8],
        [8, 9, 3, 6, 7],
        [7, 8, 9, 3, 6],
        [6, 7, 8, 9, 3]]])
```

Timings on again very large array -

```
In [294]: a = np.random.randint(0,10,10000)

In [295]: %timeit rolling_add3D(a,[1,2,3])
10000 loops, best of 3: 83.7 µs per loop
```

The performance would be proportional to the length of array to be added. So, to add a `1000` elements array into an `10000` length input array would be -

```
In [301]: a = np.random.randint(0,10,10000)

In [302]: add_array = np.random.randint(0,10,1000)

In [303]: %timeit rolling_add3D(a,add_array)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.9 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in A:
   new_list = B[:]
   new_list.append(i)
   print(new_list)
   for q in B:
        new_list = [new_list[-1]]+new_list[:-1]
        print(new_list)
   print("-"*15)
```