# Slice multiple frame of numpy array with multiple y1:y2, x1:x2

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have an numpy array of multiple frame (multiple_frames) and I want to slice height and width of each frame with different y1,y2,x1,x2 to draw a square of "1" in each frames.
(slice_yyxx) is a numpy array and contain one array of y1,y2,x1,x2 for each frame.

```py
slice_yyxx = np.array(slice_yyxx).astype(int)
nbr_frame = slice_yyxx.shape[0]

multiple_frames = np.zeros(shape=(nbr_frame, target_shape[0], target_shape[1], target_shape[2]))
print(multiple_frames.shape)
# (5, 384, 640, 1)

print(slice_yyxx)
# Value ok

print(slice_yyxx.shape)
# (5, 4)
# Then 5 array of coord like [y1, y2, x1, x2] for slice each frames

print(slice_yyxx.dtype)
# np.int64

multiple_frames[:, slice_yyxx[:,0]:slice_yyxx[:,1], slice_yyxx[:,2]:slice_yyxx[:,3]] = 1
# ERROR: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: Would all slices be of the same shape?

Comment: @Divakar Nope, all slice_yyxx elem have a different y1,y2,x1,x2 then different shape

Comment: For same shapes, you could have used a vectorized method - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353944/. For different shapes, simply loop through.

Comment: @Divakar I can't do it without loop ? :/

Comment: .......... Nope.

Comment: In general if you are producing arrays with differing shapes, it is nearly impossible to avoid (python level) loops.  The fast compiled numpy code works with whole multidimensional arrays ("rectangular"), and returns the same.  It does not operate on or produce "ragged" arrays (except in the slow object array format).

Comment: Please post an actual MCVE

Comment: I can think of a way to do this without a loop, but I need to understand what your terms mean. Frame is not a standard numpy term, and I'd like to know what `slice_yyxx` is.

Comment: why is `multiple_frame` 4D?

Comment: @Divakar. I did it without a loop :)

Comment: @hpaulj. If you only need to make an assignment, numpy allows you to do enough manipulations on the index that you can get away with it. I posted an example here.

Answer (score 1):

The real question here is how to convert arbitrary slices into something you can use across multiple dimensions without looping. I would posit that the trick is to use a clever combination of fancy indexing, [`arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html), and [`repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html).

The goal is to create an array of row and column indices that corresponds to each dimension. Let's take a simple case that is easy to visualize: a 3-frame set of 3x3 matrices, where we want to assign to the upper left and lower right 2x2 sub-arrays to the first two frames, and the entire thing to the last frame:

```
multi_array = np.zeros((3, 3, 3))
slice_rrcc = np.array([[0, 2, 0, 2], [1, 3, 1, 3], [0, 3, 0, 3]])
```

Let's come up with the indices that match each one, as well as the sizes and shapes:

```
nframes = slice_rrcc.shape[0]                       # 3
nrows = np.diff(slice_rrcc[:, :2], axis=1).ravel()  # [2, 2, 3]
ncols = np.diff(slice_rrcc[:, 2:], axis=1).ravel()  # [2, 2, 3]
sizes = nrows * ncols                               # [4, 4, 9]
```

We need the following fancy indices to be able to do the assignment:

```
frame_index = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0,   1, 1, 1, 1,   2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
row_index   = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1,   1, 1, 2, 2,   0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
col_index   = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1,   1, 2, 1, 2,   0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
```

If we can obtain the arrays `frame_index`, `row_index`, and `col_index`, we can set the data for each segment as follows:

```
multi_array[frame_index, row_index, col_index] = 1
```

`frame_index` index is easy to obtain:

```
frame_index = np.repeat(np.arange(nframes), sizes)
```

`row_index` takes a bit more work. You need to generate a set of `nrows` indices for each individual frame, and repeat them `ncols` times. You can do this by generating a continuous range and restarting the count at each frame using subtraction:

```
row_range = np.arange(nrows.sum())
row_offsets = np.zeros_like(row_range)
row_offsets[np.cumsum(nrows[:-1])] = nrows[:-1]
row_index = row_range - np.cumsum(row_offsets) + np.repeat(slice_rrcc[:, 0], nrows)
segments = np.repeat(ncols, nrows)
row_index = np.repeat(row_index, segments)
```

`col_index` will be less trivial still. You need to generate a sequence for each row with the right offset, and repeat it in chunks for each row, and then for each frame. The approach is similar to that for `row_index`, with an additional fancy index to get the order right:

```
col_index_index = np.arange(sizes.sum())
col_index_resets = np.cumsum(segments[:-1])
col_index_offsets = np.zeros_like(col_index_index)
col_index_offsets[col_index_resets] = segments[:-1]
col_index_offsets[np.cumsum(sizes[:-1])] -= ncols[:-1]
col_index_index -= np.cumsum(col_index_offsets)

col_range = np.arange(ncols.sum())
col_offsets = np.zeros_like(col_range)
col_offsets[np.cumsum(ncols[:-1])] = ncols[:-1]
col_index = col_range - np.cumsum(col_offsets) + np.repeat(slice_rrcc[:, 2], ncols)
col_index = col_index[col_index_index]
```

Using this formulation, you can even step it up and specify a different value for each frame. If you wanted to assign `values = [1, 2, 3]` to the frames in my example, just do

```
multi_array[frame_index, row_index, col_index] = np.repeat(values, sizes)
```

We'll see if there is a more efficient way to do this. One part I asked about is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63510977/2988730).

**Benchmark**

A comparison of your loop vs my vectorized solution for `nframes` in {10, 100, 1000} and width and height of `multi_array` in `{100, 1000, 10000}`:

```
def set_slices_loop(arr, slice_rrcc):
    for a, s in zip(arr, slice_rrcc):
        a[s[0]:s[1], s[2]:s[3]] = 1

np.random.seed(0xABCDEF)
for nframes in [10, 100, 1000]:
    for dim in [10, 32, 100]:
        print(f'Size = {nframes}x{dim}x{dim}')
        arr = np.zeros((nframes, dim, dim), dtype=int)
        slice = np.zeros((nframes, 4), dtype=int)
        slice[:, ::2] = np.random.randint(0, dim - 1, size=(nframes, 2))
        slice[:, 1::2] = np.random.randint(slice[:, ::2] + 1, dim, size=(nframes, 2))
        %timeit set_slices_loop(arr, slice)
        arr[:] = 0
        %timeit set_slices(arr, slice)
```

The results are overwhelmingly in favor of the loop, with the only exception of very large numbers of frames and small frame sizes. Most "normal" cases are an order of magnitude faster with looping:

**Looping**

```
        |          Dimension          |
        |   100   |   1000  |  10000  |
--------+---------+---------+---------+
F    10 | 33.8 µs | 35.8 µs | 43.4 µs |
r  -----+---------+---------+---------+
a   100 |  310 µs |  331 µs |  401 µs |
m  -----+---------+---------+---------+
e  1000 | 3.09 ms | 3.31 ms | 4.27 ms |
--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

**Vectorized**

```
        |          Dimension          |
        |   100   |   1000  |  10000  |
--------+---------+---------+---------+
F    10 |  225 µs |  266 µs |  545 µs |
r  -----+---------+---------+---------+
a   100 |  312 µs |  627 µs | 4.11 ms |
m  -----+---------+---------+---------+
e  1000 | 1.07 ms | 4.63 ms | 48.5 ms |
--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

**TL;DR**

Can be done, but not recommended:

```
def set_slices(arr, slice_rrcc, value):
    nframes = slice_rrcc.shape[0]
    nrows = np.diff(slice_rrcc[:, :2], axis=1).ravel()
    ncols = np.diff(slice_rrcc[:, 2:], axis=1).ravel()
    sizes = nrows * ncols

    segments = np.repeat(ncols, nrows)

    frame_index = np.repeat(np.arange(nframes), sizes)

    row_range = np.arange(nrows.sum())
    row_offsets = np.zeros_like(row_range)
    row_offsets[np.cumsum(nrows[:-1])] = nrows[:-1]
    row_index = row_range - np.cumsum(row_offsets) + np.repeat(slice_rrcc[:, 0], nrows)
    row_index = np.repeat(row_index, segments)

    col_index_index = np.arange(sizes.sum())
    col_index_resets = np.cumsum(segments[:-1])
    col_index_offsets = np.zeros_like(col_index_index)
    col_index_offsets[col_index_resets] = segments[:-1]
    col_index_offsets[np.cumsum(sizes[:-1])] -= ncols[:-1]
    col_index_index -= np.cumsum(col_index_offsets)

    col_range = np.arange(ncols.sum())
    col_offsets = np.zeros_like(col_range)
    col_offsets[np.cumsum(ncols[:-1])] = ncols[:-1]
    col_index = col_range - np.cumsum(col_offsets) + np.repeat(slice_rrcc[:, 2], ncols)
    col_index = col_index[col_index_index]

    if values.size == 1:
        arr[frame_index, row_index, col_index] = value
    else:
        arr[frame_index, row_index, col_index] = np.repeat(values, sizes)
```

Comment: So much for an alternative to loop+slicing based solution huh? :) Well I don't expect this to be any more efficient than a loop based one in most circumstances, but I bet this was a good challenge!

Comment: @Divakar. Exactly. A straightforward loop (with some numba thrown in) is almost certainly going to be faster

Comment: @Divakar. It's amazing how much less efficient this is than a plain loop. I've added some benchmarks.

Comment: Added runtimes with plot using `benchit`. Hopefully conveys the information in an easier way? Think ideal would be 3 different plots. Check out the wiki post. Feel free to run those at your end and see if the numbers are similar or any way different.

Comment: @Divakar. I'd separate the three regions in the plot, maybe draw 6 lines with the frames dimension as x. The connections between the segments are misleading

Comment: Hopefully looks better now.

Comment: That looks great. I'm liking this idea of benchmarking wiki posts

Answer (score 1):

This is a benchmarking post using [`benchit`](https://github.com/droyed/benchit) package (few benchmarking tools packaged together; disclaimer: I am its author) to benchmark proposed solutions.

We are benchmarking `set_slices` from @Mad Physicist's soln with `arr[frame_index, row_index, col_index] = 1` and `set_slices_loop` without any changes to get runtime `(sec)`.

```
np.random.seed(0xABCDEF)
in_ = {}
for nframes in [10, 100, 1000]:
    for dim in [10, 32, 100]:
        arr = np.zeros((nframes, dim, dim), dtype=int)
        slice = np.zeros((nframes, 4), dtype=int)
        slice[:, ::2] = np.random.randint(0, dim - 1, size=(nframes, 2))
        slice[:, 1::2] = np.random.randint(slice[:, ::2] + 1, dim, size=(nframes, 2))
        in_[(nframes, dim)] = [arr, slice] 
    
import benchit
funcs = [set_slices, set_slices_loop]
t = benchit.timings(funcs, in_, input_name=['NumFrames', 'Dim'], multivar=True)
t.plot(sp_argID=1, logx=True, save='timings.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Vectorization is a terrible thing. In this case