# Generating banded matrices using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm using the following piece of code to create a banded matrix from a generator `g`:

```
def banded(g, N):
    """Creates a `g` generated banded matrix with 'N' rows"""
    n=len(g)
    T = np.zeros((N,N+n-1))
    for x in range(N):
        T[x][x:x+n]=g
    return T
```

The usage is simple as:

```
banded([1,2,3], 3)
```

and it returns

```
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

It will used mostly to solve  a finite difference model with a given stencil for example `(-1, 1)`

Is there a better way to generate that stencil? I could not find any good NumPy Function for that.

By better I mean, faster, using less memory, removing the loop from python and sending to Numpy stack. Any (or all) of those are improvements.

Comment: Please define "better."  Shorter code?  More general (in what way)?  Faster?  Consuming less memory?  Able to work in higher dimensions?

Comment: Faster, consuming less memory, removing the loop from python and sending to numpy stack. Any (or all) of those are better.

Comment: OK.  What's a realistic input in the real program?  How long is `g` typically and how large is `N`?

Comment: `g` is not very large, varying from 2 to 32 elements (is a regular finite difference stencil). But `N` can be slightly large. Like `100000`, anythow `N` that really dictates the size of matrix. And the size grows `N**2`.

Comment: @Lin Is input an array or list?

Comment: It will be a np.array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one with [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) to give us a `2D` view into a zeros padded `1D` version of the input and as such pretty memory efficient and hence performant too. This trick had been explored numerous times - [`1`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a3293881%20%5bnumpy%5d%20np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided%20%20np.concatenate),[`2`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3293881+%5Bnumpy%5D+np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided++np.r_).

Thus, the implementation would be -

```
def sliding_windows(a, W):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    p = np.zeros(W-1,dtype=a.dtype)
    b = np.concatenate((p,a,p))
    s = b.strides[0]
    strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
    return strided(b[W-1:], shape=(W,len(a)+W-1), strides=(-s,s))
```

Sample runs -

```
In [99]: a = [1,2,3]

In [100]: sliding_windows(a, W=3)
Out[100]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 3]])

In [101]: a = [1,2,3,4,5]

In [102]: sliding_windows(a, W=3)
Out[102]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

With the same philosophy, but less messier version, we can also leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get sliding windows. [More info on use of `as_strided` based `view_as_windows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890064/).

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

def sliding_windows_vw(a, W):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    p = np.zeros(W-1,dtype=a.dtype)
    b = np.concatenate((p,a,p))
    return view_as_windows(b,len(a)+W-1)[::-1]
```

Comment: WOW! This method is the fastest by 4 orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `scipy.sparse.diags`:

Input:

```
diags([1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2], shape=(3,5)).toarray()
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  0.],
      [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  0.],
      [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.]])
```

The second list, [0, 1, 2], is an offset list. It tells how offset from the diagonal you want a certain element to be.

Comment: Joe, yes, scipy sparse is one idea. A good one indeed. In fact the second parameter can be a `range`.

Comment: For sake of comparison I tried to generate the same matrix using the sparse method and the method that I used on example, the sparse matrix was just slightly faster in matrix allocation (for a 100,000x100,000) matrix. Of course I believe that sparseness will payoff when trying to solve the inverse.

Comment: Just for sake of information, I have used `scipy.sparse.diags(g,range(len(g), shape=(N, N+len(g)-1)).toarray()`, where `N` and `g` are the same from the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use scipy's toeplitz function, which is very similar to its matlab counterpart. It is also smart around the shape, do do not worry about the it.

```
import scipy.linalg as scl

# define first column and first line
column1 = [1,0,0]
line1 = [1,2,3,0,0]

scl.toeplitz(column1, line1)
```

If you want variable sizes, use your size parameter (N) to add zeros to the columns and lines dynamically. The following is my implementation for finite differences with a minimum size of 3.

```
col = [1,0,0] + [0] * (size -3)
lin = [1,2,1] + [0] * (size -3)
m = scl.toeplitz(col, lin)
```

Output:

```
array([[1., 2., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 2., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 2., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 2.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```