# Fast compose slices of 3D numpy array as 3D subarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a 3D numpy array `x`. I want to take a subset of each slice on axis 0 (each subset is the same shape, but with start and end indices that may be different for each slice) and compose these into a separate 3D numpy array. I can achieve this with

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(24).reshape((3, 4, 2))
starts = [0, 2, 1]
ends = [2, 4, 3]

np.stack([x[i, starts[i]:ends[i]] for i in range(3)])
```

but 1) is there any way to do this in a single operation using fancy indexing, and 2) will doing so speed things up?

Comment: Would the difference between starts and ends be always same across all elements, like its 2 here?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get sliding windows. [More info on use of `as_strided` based `view_as_windows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890064/).

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

L = 2 # ends[0]-starts[0]
w = view_as_windows(x,(1,L,1))[...,0,:,0]
out = w[np.arange(len(starts)), starts].swapaxes(1,2)
```

Alternatively, a compact version leveraging [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) that generates all the required indices and then indexing into the input array, would be -

```
x[np.arange(len(starts))[:,None],np.asarray(starts)[:,None] + np.arange(L)]
```