# Extract random 2d windows of a 2d numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, stride

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(range(60)).reshape(6,10)

arr

> array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
>        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
>        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
>        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
>        [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
>        [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]])
```

## What I need:

```
select_random_windows(arr, number_of windows= 3, window_size=3)



>  array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
>            [11, 12, 13],
>            [21, 22, 23]],
>            
>            [37, 38, 39],
>            [47, 48, 49],
>            [57, 58, 59]],
>           
>            [31, 32, 33],
>            [41, 42, 43],
>            [51, 52, 53]]])
```

In this hypothetical case I'm selecting 3 windows of 3x3 within the main array (arr).

My actual array is a raster and I basically need a bunch (on the thousands) of little 3x3 windows.

Any help or even a hint will be much appreciated.

I actually haven't found any practical solution yet...since many many hours

THX!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get sliding windows. [More info on use of `as_strided` based `view_as_windows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890064/).

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

def select_random_windows(arr, number_of_windows, window_size):
    # Get sliding windows
    w = view_as_windows(arr,window_size)

    # Store shape info
    m,n =  w.shape[:2]

    # Get random row, col indices for indexing into windows array
    lidx = np.random.choice(m*n,number_of_windows,replace=False)
    r,c = np.unravel_index(lidx,(m,n))
    # If duplicate windows are allowed, use replace=True or np.random.randint

    # Finally index into windows and return output
    return w[r,c]
```

Sample run -

```
In [209]: arr
Out[209]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]])

In [210]: np.random.seed(0)

In [211]: select_random_windows(arr, number_of_windows=3, window_size=(2,4))
Out[211]: 
array([[[41, 42, 43, 44],
        [51, 52, 53, 54]],

       [[26, 27, 28, 29],
        [36, 37, 38, 39]],

       [[22, 23, 24, 25],
        [32, 33, 34, 35]]])
```

Comment: Eventhough it worked (you got the kudos thx!) ..Just worried about some warning after assigning the resulting array : 
FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.  indexing_strides = arr_in[slices].strides

Comment: @MarioFajardo That's a scikit-image specific thing. Try updating it or you can just ignore that warning.

Comment: Champion..Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can try `[numpy.random.choice()][1]`. It takes a 1D or an ndarray and creates a single element or an ndarray by sampling the elements from the given ndarray. You also have an option of providing the size of the array you want as the output.