# Write vector into matrix starting from the diagonal

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector length `n` and a `mxm` matrix. Usually `m >> n` (`m` is way bigger than `n`). I need to repeatedly write the vector into the matrix, starting at the diagonal. For example:

vector `v = [v_1, v_2, v_3]` with a `4x4` zero-matrix results in:

```
v_1,  v_2,  v_3,  0
0,    v_1,  v_2,  v_3
0,    0,    v_1,  v_2
0,    0,    0,    v_1
```

Since I have to do this quite often, it has to be reasonably fast. Right now I am looping over every row of the matrix in raw python and writing the vector into the required position, but this is slow.

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow and come back! Sorry, was distracted with another project at work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [numpy.eye](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html). Does this work for you?

```
v = [1,2,3]
N = 5
M = 10
arr = np.sum(np.eye(N, k=i, M=10) * j for i, j in enumerate(v))
arr
>>array([[1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

**Edit** (thanks to hpaulj suggestion): If your matrix is very big and with lots of 0s, you can use sparse matrices

```
from scipy.sparse import diags
arr = diags(v,offsets=[0,1,2],shape=(N,M))
print(arr.A)
>>array([[1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: SInce you mention `scipy.sparse`, try `sparse.diags([1,2,3],offsets=[0,1,2],shape=(4,4),dtype=int).A`

Comment: numpy.eye worked fast enough for my use-case! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One idea to solve it would be to pad appropriate number of zeros on either sides and get sliding windows of length `m` along it. We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get sliding windows. [More info on use of `as_strided` based `view_as_windows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890064/).

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

def extend2D(a, m):
    # Create zeros padded version
    p1 = np.zeros(m-1,dtype=a.dtype)
    p2 = np.zeros(m-len(a),dtype=a.dtype)    
    b = np.concatenate((p1,a,p2))

    # Get sliding windows along it of lengths `m` and finally flip rows
    return view_as_windows(b,m)[::-1]
```

The output would be simply sliding windowed views into a zeros padded version of input. So, if you need the output to have its own memory space, append with `.copy()` to the output.

Sample runs -

```
In [45]: a
Out[45]: array([5, 8, 6])

In [46]: extend2D(a, m=4)
Out[46]: 
array([[5, 8, 6, 0],
       [0, 5, 8, 6],
       [0, 0, 5, 8],
       [0, 0, 0, 5]])

In [47]: extend2D(a, m=5)
Out[47]: 
array([[5, 8, 6, 0, 0],
       [0, 5, 8, 6, 0],
       [0, 0, 5, 8, 6],
       [0, 0, 0, 5, 8],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 5]])
```

**Optimization-I**

If you want to get your hands dirty with `strided-indexing` by sticking to NumPy using `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` and in the process avoid that flipping at the last step in the previous approach -

```
def extend2D_v2(a, m):
    p1 = np.zeros(m-1,dtype=a.dtype)
    p2 = np.zeros(m-len(a),dtype=a.dtype)    
    b = np.concatenate((p1,a,p2))
    s = b.strides[0]
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(b[m-1:],shape=(m,m),strides=(-s,s))
```

**Optimization-II**

Optimizing further, we can initialize a zeros array and then assign the input into it -

```
def extend2D_v3(a, m):
    b = np.zeros(2*m-1,dtype=a.dtype)
    b[m-1:m-1+len(a)] = a
    s = b.strides[0]
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(b[m-1:],shape=(m,m),strides=(-s,s))
```

Timings with `n=100` and `m=10000` random data array -

```
In [97]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: a = np.random.randint(1,9,(100))

In [98]: %timeit extend2D(a, m=10000)
    ...: %timeit extend2D_v2(a, m=10000)
    ...: %timeit extend2D_v3(a, m=10000)
10000 loops, best of 3: 51.3 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 19.6 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.6 µs per loop
```

Comment: You can also use `np.pad` instead of the concatenation or zeros + assignment.

Comment: @jdehesa In my experience, `np.pad` seemed slower. So, avoided that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar answer to [Divakar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54313385) but with NumPy only. It pads the given vector with zeros and then makes a view from that buffer:

```
import numpy as np

def view_into_diagonals(v, m):
    # Add zeros before and after the vector
    v_pad = np.pad(v, [(m - 1, m - len(v))], mode='constant')
    # Current stride
    s, = v_pad.strides
    # Offset from which the first row starts
    offset = s * (m - 1)
    # Make ndarray
    view = np.ndarray(shape=(m, m),
                      dtype=v_pad.dtype,
                      buffer=v_pad.data,
                      offset=offset,
                      # Each column moves one forward, each row moves one backwards
                      strides=(-s, s))
    # Probably better not write to it
    view.flags.writeable = False
    return view

print(view_into_diagonals([1, 2, 3], 6))
# [[1 2 3 0 0 0]
#  [0 1 2 3 0 0]
#  [0 0 1 2 3 0]
#  [0 0 0 1 2 3]
#  [0 0 0 0 1 2]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```