# How to get chunks of submatrices faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a really big matrix (`nxn`)for which I would to build the intersecting tiles (submatrices) with the dimensions `mxm`. There will be an offset of `step` bvetween each contiguous submatrices. Here is an example for `n=8, m=4, step=2`:

```
import numpy as np
matrix=np.random.randn(8,8)
n=matrix.shape[0]
m=4
step=2
```

This will store all the corner indices `(x,y)` from which we will take a 4x4 natrix: `(x:x+4,x:x+4)`

```
a={(i,j) for i in range(0,n-m+1,step) for j in range(0,n-m+1,step)}
```

The submatrices will be extracted like that

```
sub_matrices = np.zeros([m,m,len(a)])
for i,ind in enumerate(a):
    x,y=ind
    sub_matrices[:,:,i]=matrix[x:x+m, y:y+m]
```

Is there a faster way to do this submatrices initialization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get sliding windows. [More info on use of `as_strided` based `view_as_windows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890064/).

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows   

# Get indices as array 
ar = np.array(list(a))

# Get all sliding windows
w = view_as_windows(matrix,(m,m))

# Get selective ones by indexing with ar
selected_windows = np.moveaxis(w[ar[:,0],ar[:,1]],0,2)
```

Alternatively, we can extract the row and col indices with a list comprehension and then index with those, like so -

```
R = [i[0] for i in a]
C = [i[1] for i in a]
selected_windows = np.moveaxis(w[R,C],0,2)
```

---

Optimizing from the start, we can skip the creation of stepping array, `a` and simply use the `step` arg with `view_as_windows`, like so -

```
view_as_windows(matrix,(m,m),step=2)
```

This would give us a `4D` array and indexing into the first two axes of it would have all the `mxm` shaped windows. These windows are simply views into input and hence no extra memory overhead plus virtually free runtime!

Comment: Is there a way to find the intersection of overlapping windows while using this approach?

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randn(n, n)

b = a[0:m*step:step, 0:m*step:step]
```

---

If you have a one-dimension array, you can get it's submatrix by the following code:

```
c = a[start:end:step]
```

If the dimension is two or more, add comma between every dimension.

```
d = a[start1:end1:step1, start2:end3:step2]
```