# Reshaping 2d NumPy array into 3d with recurring rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have a NumPy array as follows:

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20]])
```

I am looking to arrange such that it looks like this:

```
[[[6,7,8,9,10],
  [1,2,3,4,5]],
 [[11,12,13,14,15],
  [6,7,8,9,10]],
 [[16,17,18,19,20],
  [11,12,13,14,15]]]
```

So essentially a 3D array with 2x5 in each row of the array. 
The code I tried is:

```
x=np.zeros([3,2,5])
for i in range(len(arr)):
    x[i]=arr[i:i+2,:][::-1]
```

But this results in the below output:

```
[[[ 6.  7.  8.  9. 10.]
  [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.]]    
 [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]  
 [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]]

[[[ 6.  7.  8.  9. 10.]
  [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.]]    
 [[11. 12. 13. 14. 15.]
  [ 6.  7.  8.  9. 10.]]    
 [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]]

[[[ 6.  7.  8.  9. 10.]
  [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.]]    
 [[11. 12. 13. 14. 15.]
  [ 6.  7.  8.  9. 10.]]    
 [[16. 17. 18. 19. 20.]
  [11. 12. 13. 14. 15.]]]
```

Comment: When I try executing your code attempt I get an error, just as I'd expect. If I change the loop's `range` to `range(x.shape[0])` (i.e. `range(len(x))`) I get the result you want. Are you sure the array you pasted came from the above input and code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get sliding windows. [More info on use of `as_strided` based `view_as_windows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890064/).

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

x = view_as_windows(arr,(2,arr.shape[1]))[:,0,::-1]
```

This would simply be a view into the input array. Hence, there's no extra memory overhead and virtually free runtime. If you want an output with it's own memory space, append with `.copy()` there, i.e. `x.copy()`.

Sample run -

```
In [15]: from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

In [16]: view_as_windows(arr,(2,arr.shape[1]))[:,0,::-1]
Out[16]: 
array([[[ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
        [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5]],

       [[11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]],

       [[16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
        [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some [stride tricks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) to construct your array as a multidimensional sliding window over your input array:

```
import numpy as np 
arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20]]) 

# compute the strides and shape of the output array
in_strides = arr.strides 
out_strides = in_strides[:1] + in_strides 
out_shape = (3, 2) + arr.shape[-1:]  # keep the last dimension's size
strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, strides=out_strides, shape=out_shape)
out_arr = strided[:, ::-1, :].copy()  # use a copy to stay safe
```

The above will work safely as long as `out_shape[-1] <= arr.shape[1]` and `sum(out_shape[:2]) <= arr.shape[0] + 1`. These are constraints that make the sliding window meaningful inside the original array, and your actual use case should naturally respect these.

Important notes:

- If the above inequalities don't hold then the sliding window will happily slide out of the memory range of your array, and you'll silently start seeing garbage matrix elements:

  ```
  >>> out_strides = in_strides[:1] + in_strides 
  ... out_shape = (3, 3, 5)  # 3 + 3 == 6 > arr.shape[0] + 1 == 5
  ... np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, strides=out_strides, shape=out_shape)
  array([[[         1,              2,              3,              4,
                    5],
      [             6,              7,              8,              9,
                   10],
      [            11,             12,             13,             14,
                   15]],

     [[             6,              7,              8,              9,
                   10],
      [            11,             12,             13,             14,
                   15],
      [            16,             17,             18,             19,
                   20]],

     [[            11,             12,             13,             14,
                   15],
      [            16,             17,             18,             19,
                   20],
      [           384,            193, 94379169559968,              0,
                    0]]])
  ```
- If you won't mutate your array afterward, and only then, you may omit the final `.copy()` call in the above. This will give you a strided array that shares memory with the original array, but what's more important, the rows of the array will share memory with one another. This is *not* what you usually want, but if your real array is very large *and* you know you can safely assume that the values won't be independently mutated, the memory footprint might matter. Another aspect to consider is that calling `.copy()` on the result will give you a contiguous block of memory, which is probably better for performance down the line, depending on what you're planning to do with the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use any loops. Slicing suffices:

```
x = np.zeros([3,2,5], dtype=int)
x[:,0] = arr[-3:,:]
x[:,1] = arr[:3,:]
```

Essentially you assign the 0-th row in all pages to the last 3 rows of `arr`, and the 1st row in all pages to the first 3 rows of `arr`.