# reshape np array for deep learning

Tags: python, numpy, keras, reshape

I want to use keras to apply a neural network to my time-series data. TO improve the model I want to have 50 time states of input per output. The final input should have 951 samples with 50 time points of 10 features (951, 50, 10)

Therefore, I have to reshape my data. I do that doing a for loop, but is awfully slow. Is there a way to improve the code and making it faster?

Example:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.ones((1000,10))

for i in range(50, int(X.shape[0]) + 1):
     if i == 50:
        z = 0
        X2 = np.array(X[z:i, :]).reshape((1, 50, X.shape[1]))
     else:
        X2 = np.concatenate([X2, np.array(X[z:i, :]).reshape((1, 50, X.shape[1]))])
     z = z + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get sliding windows. [More info on use of `as_strided` based `view_as_windows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890064/).

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

X2 = view_as_windows(X,(50,10))[:,0]
```

It's simply a view into the input and hence virtually free on runtime -

```
In [17]: np.shares_memory(X,view_as_windows(X,(50,10))[:,0])
Out[17]: True

In [18]: %timeit view_as_windows(X,(50,10))[:,0]
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.8 µs per loop
```