# Assign a sequence at irregular intervals in 1D array - Python / NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a sequence of numbers that I would like to insert into a larger array at irregular intervals:

```
dates = np.zeros(15)
pattern = np.arange(3) + 1
starts = [2, 6, 11]
for start in starts:
    dates[start:start + pattern.size] = pattern

> [0 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 0 1 2 3 0]
```

I have to do this many (100M+) times on large (10K+) arrays, so I'm looking for a way to do this with broadcasting or another efficient method, avoiding a for loop. *pattern* will always be a range if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct a 2D selector array to select the indices of `dates` you want to modify with `numpy.add.outer`, then perform a broadcasted assignment of `pattern` into the selected indices:

```
dates[numpy.add.outer(starts, numpy.arange(len(pattern)))] = pattern
```

Answer (score 3):

We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get sliding windowed views into the output array and hence assign the new values into it. This would be pretty efficient, as we are working with views, there's no generation of explicit indices and the assignment is a vectorized and broadcasted one.

The implementation would look something like this -

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

view_as_windows(dates,pattern.size)[starts] = pattern
```

[More info on use of `as_strided` based `view_as_windows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890064/).

Comment: Ah, of course. You can't construct a view of just the windows you want, but you can construct a view of *all* the windows and then assign into specific windows.