# How to slice np array's certain dimention with different start point?

Tags: python, numpy

The sample code is as below.

I want to get `dataNew(h, w, length)` according to `data(h, w, c)` and `ind(h, w)`. Here `length < c`, it means dataNew is sliced from data.

Here, `length` and `ind[i, j]` is made sure to suit the `c` value.

I have realize it through for loops, but I wnat the python way. Please help, thanks!

```py
import numpy as np

h, w, c = 3, 4, 5

data = np.arange(60).reshape((h, w, c))
print(data)

length = 3
ind = np.random.randint(0, 3, 12).reshape(h, w)
print(ind)

dataNew = np.empty((h, w, length), np.int16)
for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
        st = ind[i, j]
        dataNew[i, j] = data[i, j][st : st + length]

print(dataNew)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get sliding windows. [More info on use of `as_strided` based `view_as_windows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890064/).

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

# Get all sliding windows along the last axis
w = view_as_windows(data,(1,1,length))[...,0,0,:]

# Index into windows with start indices and slice out singleton dims 
out = np.take_along_axis(w,ind[...,None,None],axis=-1)[...,0]
```

Last step is basically using advanced-indexing into the windows with those start indices. This could be made a bit simpler and might be easier to understand. So, alternatively, we could do -

```
m,n = ind.shape
I,J = np.ogrid[:m,:n]
out = w[I,J,ind]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be creating an indexing array using `broadcasting` and use [`np.take_along_axis`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) to index the array:

```
ix = ind[...,None] + np.arange(length)
np.take_along_axis(data, ix, -1)
```