# Numpy slicing multiple 2D ranges with an array of indices

Tags: numpy

Given an Nx2 array of N points ([row, col]):

```py
points = np.array([
  [r1, c1],
  [r2, c2],
  ...
])
```

And given a 2D matrix I want to operate on:

```py
img = np.arange(400).reshape(20,20)
```

I'm looking for an efficient way to take 2D slices of `img` using the indices.

So if I want a slice of a given height `h` and width `w`, the pseudocode would be:

```py
p_rows = points[:,0]
p_cols = points[:,1]
patches = img[p_rows:p_rows+h, p_cols:p_cols+w]
```

Such that the result would be an Nxhxw matrix. But, alas, broadcasting didn't save me this time.

I've looked at `np.r_`, `np.select`, `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`, `np.take`... But not had any luck yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get sliding windows. [More info on use of `as_strided` based `view_as_windows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890064/). Then, indexing into those windows with advanced-indexing using those indices from `points` solves it for us!

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

w = view_as_windows(img,(h,w))
out = w[points[:,0],points[:,1]]
```

Comment: I cannot use scikit on this project, but I will look at the implementation to better understand as_strided. Thanks!

Comment: @Faqinghere As mentioned in the other linked Q&A, you can simply use the source code as standalone without installing scikit-image - https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/util/shape.py.