# Slicing a 2D numpy array using vectors for start-stop indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, slice

First post here, so please go easy on me. :)

I want to vectorize the following:

```
rowStart=array of length N        
rowStop=rowStart+4        
colStart=array of length N    
colStop=colStart+4    

x=np.random.rand(512,512) #dummy test array   

output=np.zeros([N,4,4])
for i in range(N):
   output[i,:,:]=x[ rowStart[i]:rowStop[i], colStart[i]:colStop[i] ]
```

What I'd like to be able to do is something like:

```
output=x[rowStart:rowStop, colStart:colStop ]
```

where numpy recognizes that the slicing indices are vectors and broadcasts the slicing.  I understand that this probably doesn't work because while I know that my slice output is always the same size, numpy doesn't.

I've looked at various approaches, including "fancy" or "advanced" indexing (which seems to work for indexing, not slicing), massive boolean indexing using meshgrids (not practical from a memory standpoint, as my N can get to 50k-100k), and [np.take](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html), which just seems to be another way of doing fancy/advanced indexing.

I could see how I could potentially use fancy/advanced indexing if I could get an array that looks like:

```
[np.arange(rowStart[0],rowStop[0]),
 np.arange(rowStart[1],rowStop[1]), 
...,  
np.arange(rowStart[N],rowStop[N])]
```

and a similar one for columns, but I'm also having trouble figuring out a vectorized approach for creating that.

I'd appreciate any advice you can provide.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get sliding windows and hence solve our case here. [More info on use of `as_strided` based `view_as_windows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890064/).

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

BSZ = (4, 4) # block size
w = view_as_windows(x, BSZ)
out = w[rowStart, colStart]
```

Comment: @CalvintheDog Take a look at the linked post for more details that also suggest how you can get the source code of `view_as_windows` as standalone, if you don't have the package or can't install.

Comment: I may have to dig into the source code, not because I can't install the package, but because my RowStart, ColStart are not simply of the type `np.arange(0,x.shape[0],stride)`.  Instead they are determined in polar-coordinates.  I'll look at the source code to see if I can provide arbitrary chip start locations.