# How to crop each element of a numpy array with a window size at the same time without looping over each pixel?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I have a numpy array with a size of `240 x 320 x 3` and I want to use a window (window size `ws=5`) to slide over each pixel and crop out the subarray centered at that pixel. The final output dimension should be `240 x 320 x ws x ws x 3`. So I pad the original array with window size and use `for loop` to do so.

```
height = 240
width = 320
image = np.random.rand((height, width, 3))
image = np.pad(image, ((ws//2, ws//2), (ws//2, ws//2), (0, 0)), mode='reflect')
patches = np.zeros((height, width, ws, ws, 3))
for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        patches[i, j] = image[i:i+ws, j:j+ws]
```

Are there any ways to do the cropping of each pixel at the sample time? Like without using the `for loop` over each pixel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically getting sliding windows across the image. We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get sliding windows. [More info on use of `as_strided` based `view_as_windows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890064/).

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

out = view_as_windows(image,(ws,ws,1)).transpose(0,1,4,3,2,5)[:-1,:-1,...,0]

# Alternatively :
out = view_as_windows(image,(ws,ws,1))[:-1,:-1,...,0].transpose(0,1,4,3,2)
```

Also note that you are missing out on the last possible window, if you had `for i in range(height+1)` and `for j in range(width+1)`. To get the same result with our solution, the last indexing step would modify to `[...,0]` in place of `[:-1,:-1,...,0]`, thus giving us -

```
out = view_as_windows(image,(ws,ws,1))[...,0].transpose(0,1,4,3,2)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thanks.