# Slicing each row in a different way

Tags: python, numpy, slice, numpy-ndarray

I have a `numpy.array` `a` with the shape `(8, 16000, 2)` which represents 8 stereo audios each 1s long. I want to sample a 0.5s subsample from each recording. Thus, I sample start and end indices in the following way:

```py
a = np.random.rand(8, 16000, 2)
possible_starts = np.arange(8000)
start_idxs = np.random.choice(possible_starts, size=a.shape[0])
end_idxs = start_idxs + 8000
```

How to extract these different slices for each row in numpy efficienty?
I obviously can do it in loop:

```py
b = np.zeros((8, 8000, 2))
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    b[i] = a[i, start_idxs[i]: end_idxs[i], :]
```

but I want to do it in the vectorised way.

Comment: Your sample code uses `a` and `b` without defining them

Comment: @fountainhead I said it has a shape (8, 16000, 2). It can be any such np.array.

Comment: You'll get more help if you provide code to generate example data, so that we can copy, paste, and directly test the code. Think of it this way: we want to help but we are also lazy!

Comment: So, each slice would have the same shape?

Comment: @Divakar Yes, 8000 in this case

Comment: @FallenApart Did the posted solution work?

Comment: @Divakar I was surprised that there is no any simpler solution and I ended up using loop, which turned out to be quick enough. I will yet investigate it later.

Answer (score 1):

We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get sliding windowed views and thus solve our problem here in a vectorized way.

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

w = view_as_windows(a, (1,8000,1))[:,:,:,0,:,0]
b_out = w[np.arange(len(start_idxs)), start_idxs].swapaxes(1,2)
```

Or use `np.take_along_axis(w, start_idxs, axis=1).swapaxes(1,2)` for better readability as suggested by @Daniel F.

[More info on use of `as_strided` based `view_as_windows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890064/).

Given that your loop is iterating for just `8` times, you should benchmark.

Comment: `b_out = np.take_along_axis(w, start_idxs, 1).swapaxes(1,2)` might be a bit more readable?