# Rolling window over 2D array with specific spacing along one dimension

Tags: python, numpy

I understand that similar questions have been posted here before, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how `np.lib_stride_tricks.as_strided` works. I would like to know if there is a numpy function that lets me do the following mapping from `a -> b` efficiently:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(100000,3)

window_length = 200;
spacing = 20;

b = []

for i in range(0,a.shape[0] - window_length,spacing):
    b.append(a[i:i+window_length,:])

b = np.asarray(b);
print(b.shape)
```

Which outputs `(4490,200,3)`.

Comment: Note that to use full extent, use `for i in range(0,a.shape[0] - window_length+1,spacing):`.

Comment: All `numpy` arrays are stored in contiguous and linear memory segments. `strides` basically define the **jump** you make along each dimension of the data, to get the illusion of a multidimensional array. Say if the array is `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and you define jumps along x and y axis as 1 and 2, then the virtual 2d array would be `[ [1, 2], [3, 4] ]`. Note that along rows, elements (say 1 and 2) are stored contiguously, whereas along columns, you need to jump 2 locations in the original array to get to the element (1 and 3).

Answer (score 4):

We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get sliding windowed views and thus solve our problem here in a vectorized way.

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows
w = view_as_windows(a, (window_length,1), step=(spacing,1))[...,0]

# If needed, get into desired permuted axes format
out = w.swapaxes(1,2)
```

[More info on use of `as_strided` based `view_as_windows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890064/). If [`scikit-image`](https://scikit-image.org) is not available, we can directly use the [`source code`](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/util/shape.py) that works standalone.

Answer (score 0):

A direct use of `as_strided`:

```
strides = a.strides

new_len = (a.shape[0]-window_length+1)//spacing

b = as_strided(a,shape=(new_len,window_length, a.shape[1]),
               strides=(strides[0]*spacing,) + strides)
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate your array using *stride_tricks* proceed as
follows:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided as stride

d0, d1 = a.shape
s0, s1 = a.strides
b2 = stride(a,
    ((d0 - window_length + 1) // spacing, window_length, d1),
    (s0 * spacing, s0, s1))
```

I deliberately chose a different array name (*b2*).

To check that my code yields proper result:

- generate *b* array using your code,
- compare both arrays running `np.array_equal(b, b2)`.

The result should be *True*.