# Numpy as_strided for RGB images

Tags: python, numpy

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109068/implement-matlabs-im2col-sliding-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936620/using-strides-for-an-efficient-moving-average-filter) that I can use as_strided() function for images with the depth of 1, but maybe there is a way to do that with 3 channel images. For example:
I have an image of shape 128x128x3, where 3 is the depth(channels) of the image and I want to get a view into this array.

Comment: So, its `(128,128,1)` input and want to convert to  `(128,128,3)` one?

Comment: No. I have 128*128*3 image and I just want to create the view into it.

Comment: View as such doesn't mean anything.

Comment: So I need to decrease the number of channels to one so I have 128x128 image?

Comment: `array[...,0]`?

Comment: Array of shape (128, 128)

Comment: as_strided views of a single channel array can be adapted to work with a 3 channel image array.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, but how can I do that

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890064/901925

Comment: @hpaulj, You can post it as an answer. I'll accept it

Comment: I added a 3 channel example to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51866135/numpy-summation-with-sliding-window-is-really-slow